# excel - Multiple units in single pivot table column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to combine multiple units into a single column of my pivot table. I need all the units (ea,hr,m2,t,wk) to populate under a single column adjacent to the QUANTITY column. Before I add the 'units' field to the table I get the BEFORE and i just want to add the quantity the corresponds to each item to populate in a single column rather than how it does in the AFTER

[BEFORE + AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qycBx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your units to the rows area and then set your pivot table design to Tabular.

[image]